# Is there a way to grow ul li sideways when a limited number of item is reached

Tags: html, css

is there anyway to grow a list sideways when 3 items are reached. I know how to do it when the number of list is known. But when it is generated in a loop, how can we do it?

```
Item1    Item4    Item7
Item2    Item5    Item8
Item3    Item6
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's generated in a loop, create a counter that's incremented each time you add a item. :)

Then use this after your loop to do what you want:

```
if(counter%3==0)
   {
   counter = 0;
   //do cool stuff
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
ul.list{
padding:0;
margin:0;
width:100px;
}
ul.list li{
display:block;
background-color:#CCC;
padding:5px;
}
</style>

<?php
    for($ctr=1;$ctr<=10;$ctr++){
    $mod = $ctr%3;
    //echo $mod.'<br />';
    echo '<ul class="list">';
        echo '<li>Item '.$ctr.'</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
    if($mod==0){ echo '<br />'; }
   }
?>
```

Just modify

Comment: what 'div class="bal"' doing here?